# Firefox Bookmarks "Folder icon" from Linux Theme

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

W Firefoksie ikony folderów w panelu zakładek to te ikony z linuksa:
This icon from Linux is set as "Folder icon" i bookmarks panel:
/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/places/folder.png
How does Firefox relate to them?
Definitely not by path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is this icon:
moz-icon://stock/gtk-directory?size=menu